# Is it haram to watch animals kill each other and is it haram to watch animal free mixing with animal but opposite genders

Tags: halal-haram, sin, animals, doubts

I want to watch these YouTube videos of animals killing other animals or eating their dead body and animals free mixing and I want to knows if it’s halal

Comment: If these killings are by human "intervention" this act is forbidden and sinful, and therefore watching it hardly can be of any benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. They’re animals. Not humans, so the idea of looking at the opposite gender doesn’t apply because they’re animals and not people.
2. I’m deeply concerned as to why anyone would want to watch such videos. I wouldn’t say it’s haram to watch them but it’s best to stay away from such graphic material.